# Replace the records of particular category

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

There is one scenario where i need to replace the existing records from cached data with new incoming data source. Looking for the cleaner approach to handle the array operations.

For example:

```
var userCategory = [
    {
      id: 'platinum',
      name: 'bob',
    },
    {
      id: 'platinum',
      name: 'bar',
    },
    {
      id: 'platinum',
      name: 'foo',
    },
    {
      id: 'gold',
      name: 'tom',
    },
    {
      id: 'silver',
      name: 'billy',
    },
  ];
```

Here is new users of particular category

```
var newPlatinumUsers = [
    {
      id: 'platinum',
      name: 'bob',
    },
    {
      id: 'platinum',
      name: 'mike',
    },
  ];
```

This is the expected result needed:

```
  var expected = [
    {
      id: 'platinum',
      name: 'bob',
    },
    {
      id: 'platinum',
      name: 'mike',
    },
    {
      id: 'gold',
      name: 'tom',
    },
    {
      id: 'silver',
      name: 'billy',
    },
  ];
```

I tried with filtering all the platinum user from existing records then added the new records but it looks verbose

Is there any cleaner approach like lodash operator??
Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: We can't advise you on your code if you haven't provided it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**May you are looking for this.**

```js
function getUnique(arr){

// removing duplicate
let uniqueArr = [...new Set(arr)];

document.write(uniqueArr);
}

const array = ['acer','HP','Apple','Apple','something'];

// calling the function
getUnique(array);
```

**Verify my answer if it help you.**

Comment: Sorry @Nishant, I have updated the questions. I my case i need to replace the records of particular category.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the Javascript implementation of the same

```js
var userCategory = [
  { id: 'platinum', name: 'bob', },
  { id: 'platinum', name: 'bar', },
  { id: 'platinum', name: 'foo', },
  { id: 'gold', name: 'tom', },
  { id: 'silver', name: 'billy', },
];
var newPlatinumUsers = [
  { id: 'platinum', name: 'bob', },
  { id: 'platinum', name: 'mike', },
];
const result = [...newPlatinumUsers];
userCategory.forEach((node) => {
  if(node.id !== 'platinum') {
    result.push(node);
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

With this solution you can change more than one category:

```js
var userCategory = [
    {id: 'platinum',name: 'bob'},
    {id: 'platinum',name: 'bar'},
    {id: 'platinum',name: 'foo'},
    {id: 'gold',name: 'tom'},
    {id: 'silver',name: 'billy'},
  ];
  
var newUsers = [
  {id: 'platinum',name: 'bob'},
  {id: 'platinum',name: 'mike'},
  {id: 'gold',name: 'will'},
  {id: 'gold',name: 'jerry'},
];

const idsToReplace = {}

const result = [...newUsers]

result.forEach(u => {
  idsToReplace[u.id] = true
})

userCategory.forEach(u => {
  if(!idsToReplace[u.id]){
    result.push(u)
  }
})

console.log(result)
```